# Roulette Probaility

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

The problem states:

> You start gambling at a roulette table with 100 dollars. You decide you'll stop gambling when you reach 150 dollars or 0 dollars, whichever happens first. Each time you bet, you have a .27 probably of losing 25 dollars, .24  chance of gaining 25 dollars, and .49 chance of not winning any amount. Define variable and write equation that would give EXPECTED NUMBER OF BETS YOU WILL MAKE UNTIL YOU STOP GAMBLING.

I have no idea where to even start!

Answer (score 3):

Note that this is a "small"problem. Since everything is a multiple of $25$, we might as well assume that we start with $4$ gold coins, and we bet until we either have $6$ gold coins or none.

Let random variable $X$ be the number of bets until the game is over.
It looks as if we are only being asked about $E(X)$.

Let $e_1$ be the expected **further length** of the game, **given** that we have $1$ gold coin. Let $e_2$ be the expected further length of the game given that we have $2$ gold coins. Define $e_3$, $e_4$, and $e_5$ similarly.

The question asks us about $e_4$, but the other $e_i$ will be useful.

Suppose we have $1$ coin and bet. Then we can either lose, and the game is over. Or we can "draw" (probability $0.49$)and we still have $1$ coin. In that case the expected further length is still $e_1$. Or we can win (probability $0.24$) and we have an expected further length of $e_2$. Thus
$$e_1=1+ 0.49e_1+ 0.24e_2.$$

Now we do a similar analysis for $e_2,e_3,e_4,e_5$. We have
$$e_2=1+0.27e_1+0.49e_2+0.24e_3,$$
$$e_3=1+0.27e_2+0.49e_3+0.24e_4,$$
$$e_4=1+0.27e_3+0.49e_4+0.24e_5,$$
$$e_5=1+0.27e_4+ 0.49e_5.$$

Five linear equations, five unknowns. Solve. It is not as bad as it looks.